# Why I generate component wrong path

Tags: angular, typescript, powershell, command-line

[image]

I wanna generate new component in dynamic-print folder, but it create in app
can anyone help me? Thank

Comment: Which is your angular and nodejs version?

Comment: I using angular v14.2.4 and node 16.15.1

Answer (score 1):

You should write the path to CLI

```
generate component home/dynamic/print/order-print-offline
```

Comment: normally I don't need to do that, I just call cmd at home/dynamic/print/order-print-offline,  but suddenly today it's wrong path